# data.table: How to perform fastest range query on partial key match?

Tags: r, data.table

On a data.table with key defined. How fast is a range query where the search key is a partial match of the key? Example: In a large data.table (see Q1 for size), get the subset of rows having Lastname key beginning by "Jo":

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(20150731)
dtUser <- data.table(
    Lastname=c("Jansen", "Jirovski", "Jocond", "Johnson", "Johnson", "Joule", "Jozef", "Jukanen", "Kanban"),
    UserID=sample(1:100, 9, replace=FALSE),
    key="Lastname")
#    Lastname UserID
# 1:   Jansen     77
# 2: Jirovski     69
# 3:   Jocond     24
# 4:  Johnson      7
# 5:  Johnson     27
# 6:    Joule     74
# 7:    Jozef      9
# 8:  Jukanen     54
# 9:   Kanban     78

#---Query1 (OK):
dtUser[Lastname > "Jo" & Lastname < "Ju",]
#    Lastname UserID
# 1:   Jocond     24
# 2:  Johnson      7
# 3:  Johnson     27
# 4:    Joule     74
# 5:    Jozef      9

#---Query2 (Failed):
dtUser[J("Jo"),]
#    Lastname UserID
# 1:       Jo     NA
```

**Question 1**: The data.table size is potentially large (between 1 million to 10 million rows, max 100 bytes/row.) Fast performance is critical. Is the Query1 above the fastest way?

**Question 2**: In case data.table is not suitable for "ultra fast" range query search on partial key match. What is the most appropriate data structure to use in R?

**TEST RESULTS**: Using Query1 on a 1.2GB dataset: 40 million rows datatable, 4 cols (Str1, Str2, Str3, BogusInteger). StrX here is are unique short strings average length 10 chars, similar to people Lastname.

```
c(nbRows=nrow(myDT), "SizeMB"=round(object.size(myDT) / 1e6, 0))
#   nbRows   SizeMB
# 39480360     1208

setkey(myDT, Str1, Str2, Str3)

# Partial key match (slower)
system.time(dtTest <- myDT[Str1 > "tranbar" & Str1 < "tranbaz", ])
system.time(dtTest <- myDT[Str1 > "int" & Str1 < "intz" & Str2 > "mo" & Str2 < "mu", ])
system.time(dtTest <- myDT[Str1 > "int" & Str1 < "intz" & Str2 > "mo" & Str2 < "mu" & Str3 > "t" & Str3 < "u", ])

# Exact key match (faster)
system.time(dtTest <- myDT[Str1 == "transportation", ])
system.time(dtTest <- myDT[Str1 == "transportation" & Str2 == "energy", ])
system.time(dtTest <- myDT[Str1 == "transportation" & Str2 == "energy" & Str2 == "costs", ])
```

- Computer: Desktop, 8GB RAM, CPU: Q9550, Xubuntu 14.04 x64
- R 3.20, RStudio 0.99.446
- data.table 1.9.4
- Partial key match: Query duration is roughly 11 seconds per column, regardless of the rows returned (from 200,000 to 5 rows or even 0 in my various tests)
- Exact key match: much faster, almost instant for 1 column.
- Query Str1 column alone: average time 11 secs (partial), 0.02 sec (exact)
- Query Str1 & Str2: average time 23 secs (partial), 3.2 secs (exact)
- Query Str1 & Str2 & Str3: average time 35 secs (partial), 5.3 secs (exact)

Comment: Plese define `large`: 10Mb, 1GB, 4 GB,yadayadayada

Comment: Large, in my case, is between 1 million to 10 million rows. Columns are pretty small to contain minimal necessary info to allow the fastest search. In average a row size is around 100 bytes max. So in the largest case, 10 millions rows x 100 bytes = 1GB dataset size. May be 1GB is not big enough, I think the question is still relevant. I'd like to know the fastest way to make range query on partial key match on data.table. May be in a future project.

Comment: Thanks. If that is the case, did you apply query 1 to your real data?  Show us the summary of result, if you did.

Comment: @user227710 Sorry for taking sometimes to fake a big dataset. I have updated the original post to include the benchmark results as you suggested. In the test I made, querying by partial key match on 2 key columns would take roughly 25 secs. I hope there is a way to perform faster. Whether with data.table or not.

Comment: It sounds to me that your query 1 is already fast. I am not sure how much superfast you want it to be.

Comment: @user227710 I don't know the inner working of data.table when it comes to partial key match. May be there is a good practice for this way of querying. Let's hope an expert will jump in to give some advice.